# Is this an anti-pattern, or is there a simpler way to detect if a Vue is destroyed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have Vue instances which continually poll for some status, and I want to cancel the polling if the instance is destroyed.

Currently, I do the following logic, but curious if there's a built-in property or method to simplify this:

```
export default {
   data: () => ({
       destroyed: false // seems like an anti-pattern
   }),
   beforeDestroy(){
       this.destroyed = true; // seems like an anti-pattern
   },
   methods: {
      check(){
          if (this.destroyed) return; // would prefer this.$isDestroyed
          if (await forSomething()) {
              return this.check();
          }
      }
   },
   mounted(){
      this.check();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't respond to beforeDestroy() or destroyed() by canceling any timers? The usual need for intercepting those events is to clean up resources. I'd probably initiate any local cleanup in beforeDestroy(), and if I needed to inform a remote service of something I might do it from destroyed().

Comment: I don't really have timers, it's more recursive functions that need to know when to exit

Comment: You can't interrupt function execution, recursive or otherwise. JavaScript is single-threaded

Comment: @Phil if you check my example, you'll see that it checks before re-running.

Comment: I think this is fine. I've used `_isDestroyed`. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L54. But it's never mentioned in docs. I was read from somewhere said it's quite safe to use (I can't find it now).

Comment: It'e fine. Vue doesn't have a public API for figuring out if a component is destroyed, so you'll have to flag the destruction yourself and act accordingly, which you've done.